# Spring Boot Redis Architectural Design

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, architecture

I would like to ask for some advice regarding the system design for the application I am currently working at. We have a story feature similar to instagram and as a back-end language we are using Java Spring and I have just implemented a Redis cache.

The current layers are like this:

Controller -> Service -> Repository ( Jpa Interface) -> Domain

We will be implementing some caching for a lot of data ( like the user stories of users ).
From a Java architectural point of view does it make sense to add a DAO layer between the service and repository layers where the data source ( aka cache or actual database ) will be chosen. Also does it make sense to actually create a "cache domain" that is a data structure that represents the domain object but is specifically created to be stored in the cache ( a bit like a dto, but for example for a user story I could have a field that shows earliest story element remove time so I know when I can remove certain entries).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to have caching defined in front of service layer (admittedly, technically there's no restriction in using cache in b/w Service and Repository either), this way your data flow will look like following

Controller -> ServiceCache -> Service -> Repository ( Jpa Interface) -> Domain

The ServiceCache layer (the "cache domain") contract must confirm to Service layer interface. In fact, both ServiceImpl and ServiceCache will implement same (Service) layer interfaces. All methods in ServiceCache should be simple delegate to ServiceImpl layer. This way you can transparently replace Service beans injected in Controllers with that of ServiceCache (say by using [spring @Qualifier](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation)). You do not have to have to have all ServiceCache built this way, go incrementally as you add caching capabilities to your beans.

The ServiceCache should enable [spring cache abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), this is more or less de-facto standard for spring applications. This way all caching work is managed by spring itself and you don't have to deal with low level caching constructs by yourself. You should add appropriate hooks in you application to ensure proper eviction and re-population of cache as per your business/technical rules (say using create/update events in service/persistence layer). This can be accomplished using @CachePut, @CacheEvict annotated methods in ServiceCache layer which shall be invoked appropriately by your application specific hooks responsible for updating/deleting cache objects.

Spring cache further abstracts actual cache technology and give you freedom to switch them as may be appropriate without any change in your caching code/logic (e.g. use in memory [caffine cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) for unit tests and [redis](https://www.journaldev.com/18141/spring-boot-redis-cache) OR [ehhcache](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-ehcache) for production). I'll strongly recommend to understand all options available from spring cache and use them effectively for cachce management. Following articles are good start -

1. [A Guide To Caching in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)
2. [Spring Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I will study the resources you gave.

Comment: Could I face any limitations using the cache abstraction ? Most tutorials showcase the use of RedisTemplate which is another an actual class that you call manually. Would there be any advantages using RedisTemplate ?

Comment: Under the hood RedisTemplate and RedisCache uses same connection and settings (both are part of spring-data-redis project). Advantage with spring cache is the abstraction for low level work (e.g. serialization/deserialization) and ease of integration in existing data flows. I personally will prefer cache abstraction and look at RedisTemplate **only** if something is not possible with cache abstraction for my caching needs - admittedly, I am yet to come across any such requirement across multiple applications where I have used spring cache already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful ! I have one last question. RIght now if the Redis server is down the application dosen't start. I tried to create a custom error handler but it still fails. Could you point me to some useful resources ?